# GWT-Can all sub widgets under TabPanel be identical?

Tags: html, gwt, smartgwt, uibinder

I am creating a TabPanel with 2 sub widgets in it now. Basically the 2 sub widgets(getGrid1() and getGrid2()) are identical except some user input text validation difference when submitting.

```
TabPanel tabPanel = new TabPanel();

grid1 = getGrid1();
panel1 = new SimplePanel(grid1);

grid2 = getGrid2();
panel2 = new SimplePanel(grid2);

tabPanel.add(panel1, new HTML("Tab1"));

tabPanel.add(panel2, new HTML("Tab2"));

tabPanel.selectTab(0);

dialogBox.add(tabPanel);
```

Based on my code, those 2 tab name is visible, but there is no content in the 1st tab, the content in tab 2 is full visible. I also tried to add another sub widget which is also identical to other 2 widgets except some validation difference, only the 3rd widget content is visible.

Any idea of how to deal with it? What I want is having 3 identical widgets under TabPanel except some validation difference.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code for `getGrid1()` and `getGrid2()`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Just found the source code of this add method in GWT TabPanel has a comment in it : Inserts a widget into the tab panel. If the Widget is already attached to the TabPanel, it will be moved to the requested index.    Seems we cannot add duplicate one.

Comment: My guess is that `getGrid1()` and `getGrid2()` both return the same instance. Just create different instances and it should work fine.

Comment: You win!! It's working now after creating different instance for it. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that getGrid1() and getGrid2() both return the same instance. Just create different instances and it should work fine.